# Flutter camera freezes when start recording video on Android

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

Here are the logs I'm getting after start recording the video.

```
I/flutter (26542): startVideoRecording
I/RequestQueue(26542): Repeating capture request cancelled.
I/CameraDeviceState(26542): Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
E/CameraDevice-0-LE(26542): Surface with size (w=3840, h=2160) and format 0x22 is not valid, size not in valid set: [2048x1536, 1920x1440, 2048x1080, 1920x1080, 2560x800, 1440x1080, 1280x960, 1280x720, 1280x480, 1280x400, 864x480, 640x640, 800x480, 720x480, 768x432, 640x480, 576x432, 640x360, 480x360, 480x320, 384x288, 352x288, 320x240, 240x160, 176x144, 160x120]
E/CameraDevice-0-LE(26542): submitRequestList - cannot use a surface that wasn't configured
```

Comment: Have you disposed the camera controller?

Comment: Yes, I have done that.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. You cannot record at requested resolution. If you cannot set supported resolution, you probably have a device that flutter camera plugin doesn't support. You should complain on the camera plugin GitHub.